# sp_help system stored procedure doesn't show what are INPUT and OUTPUT parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

`sp_help mystoredprocname` shows the list of parameters. But it doesn't show which are INPUT and which are OUTPUT parameters:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBShR.jpg]

`sp_helptext mystoredproc` returns the entire stored procedure with input and output params. I want to see only the INPUT and OUTPUT parameters

I want see the list of INPUT and OUTPUT params for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: the system table **parameters** has the information of the parameters os all stored procedures, and the column **is_output** is what you need, but for `SQL Server 2005` I don't know if works...

Answer (score 1):

You need to look deeper than sp_help for this. You would look at sys.parameters. is_output will tell you the direction of the parameter.

```
select * from sys.parameters
where object_id = object_id('spBasam_GetEmployeeCountByGender')
```

Comment: Got it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT  sp.name 
      , parm.name
      , case WHEN parm.is_output = 1 
             THEN 'output' 
             ELSE 'input' 
              END AS 'paramType'
  FROM sys.procedures sp
  JOIN sys.parameters parm ON sp.object_id = parm.object_id
 WHERE sp.name = 'spBasam_GetEmployeeCountByGender'
```

This query only give your store procedure name and return parameter's name with input or output type.

You can use another info from `sys.procedures` and `sys.parameters` result.